# powershell replace "ID= a long number"

Tags: variables, search, powershell, replace

I am using a Find and Replace script found on StackOverflow.

```
Get-Content test.txt | `
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "foo", "bar" } | `
Set-Content test2.txt
```

and as long as i am searching for foo and want to replace it with bar this works great.

My problem is that I want to replace ID="*123456789" where the numbers are different every time. So the only thing i know for sure is that i want to search for "ID="* and the rest is variable. When i use my good friend to find a answer to this question i don't get anything because the word variable is in it.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of the -replace opeartor is a regex, so:

```
Get-Content test.txt | 
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "ID=\d+", "bar" } | 
Set-Content test2.txt
```

Also, the -replace operator will work just as well on an array, so unless your file is really large you can also do this:

```
(Get-Content test.txt) -replace "ID=\d+", "bar" | Set-Content test2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your rappid reply!

i will test this, but is it posible to change "bar" to the current "yearmonthday_hourminute" that would be great!